# mongodb non ascii character detected

Tags: python, mongodb

```
> db.user.find()
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::UserException'
  what():  non ascii character detected
Wed Dec 14 13:29:38 mongo got signal 6 (Aborted), stack trace: 

Wed Dec 14 13:29:38 0x809d07d 0x8095cc3 0xa14400 0xa14416 0xa3fe71 0xa4334e 0x1be0b5 0x1bbfa5 0x1bbfe2 0x1bc14e 0x80ecd53 0x8117479 0x810c718 0x3c36f0 
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x2d) [0x809d07d]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z12quitAbruptlyi+0x333) [0x8095cc3]
 [0xa14400]
 [0xa14416]
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x51) [0xa3fe71]
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17e) [0xa4334e]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x155) [0x1be0b5]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xabfa5) [0x1bbfa5]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xabfe2) [0x1bbfe2]
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0xac14e) [0x1bc14e]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5mongo9uassertedEiPKc+0x183) [0x80ecd53]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5mongo9Convertor8toStringEP8JSString+0x149) [0x8117479]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5mongo12native_printEP9JSContextjPy+0x98) [0x810c718]
 /usr/lib/xulrunner-2.0/libmozjs.so(+0xac6f0) [0x3c36f0]
```

the data i inserted into mongodb is encoded with utf-8, however when i use db.user.find() in console, I got the error above.

The OS is Ubuntu 11.04
Mongodb was installed through package manager

Comment: Ascii is not unicode. You may just need to change the encoding on the database. Not sure how to do this in mongodb

Comment: mongodb stores every string as unicode in its database, no need to convert. maybe your exception is because of the console encoding?

Comment: @FelixYan I tried using unicode string , does not work either.

Comment: Did you try to do the `find()` in python using pymongo?

Comment: @FelixYan Yes I tried, the result shows that the data is unicode encoding. like this {u'nick': u'\u82d7\u5973\u963f\u98de', u'_id': u'1876551191'}

Comment: so there is no problem either with your mongodb or your data. maybe your system locale matters? could you paste a `locale`'s output?

Comment: What is your code to insert data? Did you insert it with u'your_utf_string_here'? If not, the data will be encoded with default encoding. Your \u82d7\u5973\u963f\u98de looks invalid to me. What was the data you tried to insert?

Comment: My bet is this is not a problem with the data or the Mongo engine but with your display settings, and that the exception occurs when trying to print the data rather than when reading it out of the collection.

Comment: @Nat the data is surely not invalid, it's the correct form for python unicode strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB 'error: non ascii character detected' on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714990/mongodb-error-non-ascii-character-detected-on-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue. MongoDB **shell version: 1.8.2** on **Ubuntu** (EC2)

> > db.tweets.find();
>
> error:non ascii character detected

Consensus is that upgrading to the latest version of MongoDB will solve the issue.

Checked which version of MongoDB I was running by issuing the command:

> $ mongod --version
>
> db version **v1.8.2**, pdfile version 4.5 - 
>   Wed Oct 24 15:43:13 git version: nogitversion

*Confirm* if mongo is currently running:

> $ ps -deaf | grep **mongod**
>
> **mongodb  15408**     1  0 Jun06 ?  13:50:00 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

To [Shutdown MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo)

> $ ./mongo
>
> > use admin
>
> > db.shutdownServer()
>
> server should be down...

Then upgraded following these instructions: [How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Add the 10 Gen (creators of MongoDB) public key to apt-get so you trust their package:

> $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
>
> $ echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list

Update your packages:

> $ sudo apt-get update

install 10gen's MongoDB Debian/Ubuntu package:

> $ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
>
> The following packages will be **REMOVED**:
>     **mongodb**
>
> The following **NEW** packages will be installed:
>     **mongodb-10gen**

*If you get an error*, try:

> $ apt-get autoremove

Confirm that the **mongodb** user/group has permission to write to the data directory:

> $ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/.

Restart MongoDB with the command:

> $ mongod --fork --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --smallfiles --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend

Once you have the new version of MongoDB the "non ascii" character issue should be gone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on some similar reports I have seen (at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages and http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/e8b858078101933d)
it seems like the problem could be that your version of mongo/spidermonkey lacks UTF8 support. Perhaps try a fresh install or build from scratch and see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to sove this issue. I ran the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git
cd mongo
scons mongoshell
```

This will build only the mongo shell, without having to do a complete rebuild.