# mongo console client understanding UTF-8

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, console

I save the UTF-8 document into MongoDb. When I show into mongo console client, I have errors or crash:

```
>db.folders.find();
error:non ascii character detected
```

How I can look data of the document into MonoDb by console client?

Comment: I supose you are using Windows. More details about your OS are needed to be able to help you.

Comment: I use Windows and putty. Putty support UTF-8. The Mongodb startet under Linux: uname: Linux

Comment: I d't have problem with My application, when reads/store UTF-8 string from MongoDb by C driver.

Comment: MongoDB should always only take utf-8, can you also show an example of what you saved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb non ascii character detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500258/mongodb-non-ascii-character-detected)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14789539/752603

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB handles UTF-8 by default, and without configuration.  Your problem is with your PuTTy configuration.

Try setting the option "Window > Translation > Received data assumed to be in which character set:" to UTF-8.

Comment: I set the putty encoding UTF-8, but I have mongo console error : non ascii character detected

Comment: Error in the building: $ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.4
Thu Nov  1 14:33:07 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test

Comment: Two things:  (1) You're using a *very* old version of MongoDB.  The current version is 2.2.1.  (2) I suggest that you download the latest pre-built binaries for Windows and see if you have the problem there. <http://www.mongodb.org/downloads>