# Is there any better shell for mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb, ide, editor, utility

Is there any replacment for mongo.exe? I test few available  GUI environment for Mongo, unfortunately none allow executing command directly.

Is there any better tools for entering mongodb queries, that at least support Unicode characters and have a multi line editing environment? (even as simple as Notepad)

I tried PowerShell ISE, but it halt after invoking mongo.exe.

Comment: Have you tried 2.2 shell?  there is better support for multi-line commands and you can also save long documents/commands in a variable and edit it (by defining EDITOR string).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Currently I am using Mongo 2.2 shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found:

- [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) — is a shell-centric cross-platform open source MongoDB management tool (i.e. Admin GUI). Robomongo embeds the same JavaScript engine that powers MongoDB's mongo shell. Everything you can write in mongo shell — you can write in Robomongo!
- a PhpStorm plugin that provides a good unicode Monogo shell. 
  https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out a web based tool, take a look at [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/).  Other than hosting services, they provides a simple GUI interface to manage your DBs.

Comment: Thanks, But I need a windows app

Answer (score 0):

You can always just start python, import the [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) driver, and run commands from there.  Another benefit is that you could import more complicated python scripts you have already written and saved as .py files.